# ACF PRO take different menus in pages with different taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I would like to get a different main menu for pages that have different taxonomies.

PAGE COMPANY-1 (Taxonomy: COMPANY-1)
menu-1:

- Who we are COMPANY-1
- Where we are COMPANY-1
- Contacts COMPANY-1

PAGE COMPANY-2 (Taxonomy: COMPANY-2)
menu-2:

- Who we are COMPANY-2
- Where we are COMPANY-2
- Contacts COMPANY-2

PAGE COMPANY-3 (Taxonomy: COMPANY-3)
menu-3:

- Who we are COMPANY-3
- Where we are COMPANY-3
- Contacts COMPANY-3

Has anyone worked on a similar problem before? Thanks

in function.php

```
register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'menu-company-1' => esc_html__( 'Menu company 1', 'name_theme' ),
            'menu-company-2' => esc_html__( 'Menu company 2', 'name_theme' ),
            'menu-company-3' => esc_html__( 'Menu company 3', 'name_theme' ),
        )
    );
```

in header.php:

```
    <?php $company = get_field( 'company' );
    $terms = get_term_by( 'id', $company, 'taxcompany' );
    if ( $terms ) :
    // I suppose there must be the condition here to call the different menus
    endif; ?>
```

I tried using an in_category condition, but it doesn't work.

```
if ( in_category( 'company-1' ) ) {
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-company-1', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu'
      ) );
    } elseif ( in_category( 'company-2' ) ) {
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-company-2', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
    } else {
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-company-3', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu = 'menu-company-1'; // default

global $wp_query;
// instead of checking in_category() work it out from global query and set different menu as variable $menu
// print_r($wp_query);

wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => $menu, 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
```